# Load balancing with IIS and ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, load-balancing

Greetings,

What do I have to consider when you are coding an ASP .Net website in regards to if the application will run in a environment where there is a load balancer for the IIS?

All user sessions are running by them self with no shared data between sessions. Single connections to MSSQL. Images and files for download will be hosted on one single server.

Windows Server 2008's, C# and .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious item is session state.  If you are load balancing, multiple requests from the same user may move between servers.  The default session provider for ASP.NET (in-proc) doesn't support this (the user would get a new session each time they moved).  The easiest solutions are to move to a ASP.NET state server or SQL Server sessions.

FYI: Both of these solutions require that everything that you put into Session be [Serializable].  The in-proc provider doesn't have this requirement, so you may see some runtime errors and need to modify your code when you change providers.

Comment: Note that your load balancer probably has an option called "sticky sessions" or affinity that would send users to the same server that they were randomly assigned.  This will hurt your load balancing somewhat but it does let you keep using in-proc session state.

Comment: The problem with relying on sticky is that it is usually a 'best-effort' feature (users can still move between servers in some circumstances) and debugging cases where "I just got logged out for no reason" can be VERY tricky.

Comment: You can also use the Windows Server AppFabric Caching to store session state. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to move your session state into the session state service. Avoid keeping objects in session...if you must keep an object in session, make sure it's marked with the Serializable attribute (this is how it is stored, by serialization).

In general, avoid using Sessions. Keep in mind that ASP.Net Session != FormAuthentication. Chances are that your database will be a bottleneck long before the web server, depending on the nature of the application.